# How to setup environment for SpagoBI debugging

Tags: eclipse, debugging, spagobi

Does anybody succeed to debug Spago BI in Spago studio or eclipse or whatever ide?
If so please give a tip howto setup env for debugging.
I am trying to debug lates spagoBI ver. 5.0

Comment: I have postoed question on a spago forum as well  
http://www.spagoworld.org/jforum/posts/list/0/3325.page#10683

Comment: had you success with spagobi and eclipse??? i really need it! thanks

Comment: No. Somehow I finished it without debugging. Thanks a God it is done. Really hard to work with Spago.

Comment: i'm debugging now...but it was a pain understanding how to!!! and even debugging it on tomcat i didn't understood why eclipse isn't founding some resource such some file when debugging....

Answer (score 1):

There is a post about loading spagobi source into eclipse at http://www.spagoworld.org/jforum/posts/list/1142.page#3804 , where it refers to a tutorial on how to set that up. You will need to request access to the tutorial.

Presumably you could then either debug / launch the modules in eclipse/tomcat or  deploy the war files into a debug enabled tomcat abs then attach your spagobi project to that tomcat instance. Either way, you should be able to trace through the code and set break points, etc.

Comment: Project is finished without debugging. At the moment I have no access to environment where I have benn worked on spago project so I can not confirm if it will work.